# Usage of created variable from explorative factor analyses for multi-level-analysis

Tags: multi-level, factor-analysis

I have created a variable (from the original dataset of world values survey wave 7 https://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/WVSDocumentationWV7.jsp (wvs7)) that measures patriarchal gender role orientations with an exploratory factor analysis and then saved it as a variable in factor scores. Now I want to use the variable to perform ML analyses with it (country comparisons).
I used the following variables for the EFA: Q29 (men make better political leaders), Q30 (university is more important for a boy), Q31 (men make better business executives), Q33 (when jobs are scarce, men should have more right to job than women), Q35 (if a women earns more money than her husband, its almost certain to cause problems) (p. 15ff. of Codebook Variables report wvs7).

```
              #EFA and variable creation:
              efa_data2 <- wvs7 %>% select(menbetterpol, unimoreimp, menbetterbusiness,                        jobsscarce, gend_income_issue) 
              efa_data_c2 <- efa_data2[complete.cases(efa_data2), ]
              fit2 <- factanal(efa_data_c2, 1, rotation = "varimax")
              print(fit2, digits=2, cutoff=.3)
              f <- EFA(efa_data_c2, n_factors=1)
              scores <- FACTOR_SCORES(efa_data_c2,f)$scores
              summary(scores)
```

I can't get the "scores" variable to work for my original wvs7 dataset now - i.e. to add it back in there
Do you have an idea? How do I do that?
I'm using the 7th wave of World Values Survey Dataset. Let me know which information you need to help me. As you see I'm a beginner in social data analysis.
Thx for your help!

I have no idea how to make the "scores" variable work for my wvs7 dataset. And I need help on how to get the "scores" variable to work for my original wvs7 dataset now - i.e. to add it back in there.